# Is Superman an American citizen?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In *Batman vs Superman*, Superman is apparently killed and is accorded a state funeral. His coffin has the US flag draped over it and he is accorded a military gun salute. In addition, a "missing man" formation fly past is conducted.

Does this mean Superman is a US citizen?

Comment: US flag draped coffin was empty. His body was in a coffin in Smallville.

Comment: _"I grew up in Kansas. I'm as American as it gets."_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't know about "movieverse" but original continuity has Supes granted citizenship by an act of Congress, later extended by the UN to all member nations.  Clark Kent, as a distinct legal entity, has citizenship under foundling statutes that presume American citizenship for any infant found in US territory.  This is especially applicable since the Kents legally adopted him through an orphanage.  (Of course, they never let on that they found him in a rocket ship.)  Sorry that I can't cite specific issue numbers.

Comment: The details of the Kents' parental status have changed over the years.  Originally it's as you suggested - they report him as a foundling and say they'd like to adopt him, and his super-abilities wreak (comedic) havoc in the orphanage, and they rush the paperwork through. In the Byrne era, the farm gets snowed in, and they just pretend he was naturally born to Martha over the winter. I'm not sure if that's not still the version used now.

Answer (score -3):

Clark Kent is definitely a American citizen.

After all he was all but raised on Earth, by humans.
He went to school.
He had jobs.
I assume he paid his taxes.
So if that is not being a citizen of a country then I don't know what is.

Superman was a special case. He served America more than any other country.
He acts mainly on American soil.
And from what we've seen in Batman V Superman, as long as he did not caused international incidents, even the US government was more than happy to turn a blind eye, on what he did and why.

And he died with full American honors. Given to fallen combatants.

I guess that was the least they could do, seeing they nuked Superman and Doomsday. And gave Lex Luthor control over alien technology.
Although the alien technology part was entirely Superman fault!
He should've known better than to simply allow the primitive humans to mess with technology they had no business messing with.
He should've known that kryptonian technology would offer humanity a dangerous technological advantage. Advantage that could've been used against him.

You know, typical Superman stuff.
That has been shown countless times in comics.

Comment: "So if that is not being a citizen of a country then I don't know what is." — "Citizen" generally refers to a person who possesses legal [citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizenship) in a country, not someone who's just an upstanding member of society.  You can be an immigrant to the US (legally or illegally), grow up there, get jobs, & pay taxes, and still not be a citizen.

Comment: DACA is proof that Clark Kent is *not* an American Citizen.

Comment: On at least one occasion Superman has relinquished his American citizenship in the comics.

Comment: @jwodder - good luck getting a work permit as a Kryptonian.  No standardized identity documents to prove who you are.  No embassy to help support your claim.  Superman may be a nearly-unstoppable force, but bureaucracy is closer still to being an unmovable object.

Comment: It would be awfully hard to deport someone to a planet that no longer exists.